# Improving the performance of Jquery Autocomplete with Sphinx / Memcache....or?

Tags: autocomplete, memcached, sphinx

I have a list of 43,000 UK locations in an InnoDB table that I am using to populate a Jquery autocomplete box via remote json calls.

At present I'm just performing a basic SELECT * FROM locations WHERE title LIKE 'lond%' query to retrieve the requests, but even while this site is still in development, the results are coming up slow.

I've implimented a delay of 200ms between key presses and a minimum of 4 chars before it starts collecting results, but I may need to re-think this as there are some 3 char UK locations and I'd quite like it to display results immediately.

An obvious improvement would be to fulltext index 'title', but as the rest of the database is InnoDB I'd rather not go backwards and convert the table to MyISAM. Therefore I'm left with the other two tools at my disposal which are Sphinx and Memcached.

Sphinx - From what I remember Sphinx only returns the ID's of matching results, so I'd still need to query MySQL with every user keypress that triggers a lookup. Therefore I'm not sure how much of an improvement it would be?

Memcached - I had considered loading all 43,000 results into memory and then performing some sort of array search (or memcache built-in search if it has one?). But this feels a bit idotic? Or am I just over thinking it?

I'd really appreciate some feedback on the best route to take...

Comment: An important question, do you even have an index on the title column? (a normal index, not a FT one)

Comment: Goof question, and no I don't. I wasnt sure whether a standard index would help in this situation?

Comment: Yes a standard index would definitly help. Mysql should be able to do prefix matches with it (which can be implemented as a range search)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sphinx**: 
You could store the location name in a string attribute (ie both a field and an attribute). Then you could run your query entirely in sphinx (no need for db access). This would be the ulimate solution IMHO. 
(attributes are stored in memory, but still storing that much is not a big deal)

**Sphinx + MySQL**:
But even just getting the ID, and then doing a primary key lookup on your database table should be quicker than native mysql. Even quicker if you elimate sql and use HandlerSocket.

**Memcache**:
No there is no search. Its key lookups only. You could perhaps construct a key-lookup version, basically just storing all possible searches. But will be storing a lot, and still have to cope with misses (in case everything evicted)

... so its not really any differnt to just sticking memcache in front of sphinx, or even mysql. (which if you have memcache, might as well!)

**Redis**: 
If you really wanted to implement the memory only lookup maybe Redis would work.

(The ironic thing, if using sphinx, memcache or redis, whatever, you effectivly creating a second 'fast lookup' index. A copy of the original data table, setup specificly to enable searches. In which case you could just create a duplicate of your table in MyISAM to archive the same effect, even if leave the original in InnoDB)

Comment: Thanks for the input. Yes thats very true about the 2nd index. My other thought was that if I'm going to create a 2nd table in mySQL just for lookups, why not skip MyISAM and just go straight for a MEMORY table? I'll need to recreate it on every server reboot, but wouldn't that be even quicker than MyISAM with indexes and similar speed to sphinx+memcache without the code rewrite?

Comment: I doubt MEMORY engine is going to do much better. It doesnt have particully good indexes (it not often noticed because it is memory), so a search is going to be CPU intensive instead. And once doing a number of quieries, innodb is going to cache (in memory), so performance will be comparable. But at the end of the day - try it. Its completely trival to create a duplicate of the table in MyISAM or HASH, and run some queries against it.

Comment: Thanks again for the response. I have just given MEMORY a try and it is definitely more snappy at returning the responses that InnoDB. But how this will scale in the long run I have no idea. With this in mind I think I might give your initial Sphinx attribute route a try. I wasn't aware that it could return anything other than ID's, so this sounds ideal.